# MS Subcriptions REST API returns empty value

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, subscription, azure-rest-api

I register a new app to my Azure tenant and then use the Subscription REST API below to get my subscription id. But, it returns an empty value.

Is this a bug of the REST API, or the app is missing some required configurations?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list?tabs=HTTP

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **API permission** like below:

[image]

I generated the **access token** via Postman using below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to get subscriptions, I got **same response** as you like below:

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get the **desired** results, make sure to assign required **role** like `Reader` to the service principal under your subscription like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Your Subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment***

[image]

Now I generated **`token`** again and got the **subscription details** like ID successfully with below API call:

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you want to list ***all*** subscriptions, then assign `Reader` role to your service principal under **management group** level instead of specific **subscription**.